# php foreach find similar items

Tags: php, foreach, similarity

In the following scenario:

```
$array = array (
    'business', 'businesses', 'business man', 'apple'
);
print '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $row) {
    print ' <li class=""> ' . $row . '</li>';
}
print '</ul>';
```

I would like to be able to to find similar items and assign css class to it.
In the above business, businesses and business man, should be similar items.

Comment: There is a single quote (`'`) missing in front of `business man`, and a semicolon (`;`) behind the bracket in line 3.

Comment: You have to define similar. Contains the same word? But what is with 'the' then? Similarity like finding typos can be done with the hamming distance but it is not fool proof, you also need a dictionary.

Comment: Also if you want to understand semantics like business=corporation etc. Then it is close to impossible... if you succeed you could build the next generation of search engines!

Comment: As @maraca said, you need to define what *similar* means and provide enough examples in order for us to help find a good solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `strpos` to check if a string is included in another string:

```
$array = array(
    'business', 'businesses', 'business man', 'apple'
);

print '<ul>';
foreach ($array as $row) {
    $className = '';

    if (stripos($row, 'business') !== false) {
        $className = 'business';
    }

    print '<li class="'.$className.'">' . $row . '</li>';
}
print '</ul>';
```

This will add the class `business` to each word ("`$row`") in your array that contains the word "business", ignoring the case (lowercase or uppercase characters are treated the same).

Comment: in the above example I have used keyword business, but there will be many other words in array. I just want to find similarity between them

Answer (score 0):

I would use something like:

`similar_text()` - http://php.net/similar_text

or

`levenshtein()` - http://php.net/levenshtein

Then loop through every element in the array and group by "smallest levenshtein distance" or "most similar text"